# Fill a table with a foreign key by default values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I hope you could help me for that.
I have two table, i want them to be related :

```
create_table "personals", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "trigramme"
t.string   "nom"
t.string   "prenom"
t.string   "poste"
t.text     "bio"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

and

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
end
```

I have executed this :

`rails generate model Personal trigramme:string nom:string ... user:references` in order to create the foreign key and i put the `belong_to` (in Personal) and the `has_one` (in User) in the model files.

Do you know how I could generate default value in the table `Personal` when an user create an account ? I mean create a new row in `Personal` table, liked to the row created in `User` when the account is created?

My table `User` is correctly fill when an user create an account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice to create has_one relation is to use the ActiveRecord callback `before_create`. ActiveRecord automagically fills in the foreign key in the child record after it saves the parent record (on create). ActiveRecord then saves the child record as part of creating the parent record.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :personal
  before_create :generate_profile

  protected

  def generate_profile
    self.build_personal
  end

end
```